# PHP INPUT GET is not equal to PHP string

Tags: php

I want to load some pages by GET input, But When I try to compare it with if, would not work.

URL:

```
localhost/?page=تست_پیج
```

OR

```
http://localhost/?page=%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA_%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%AC
```

Then When I try with below code

```
if($_GET['page']=="تست_پیج"){
...code
}
```

OR

```
if($_GET['page']=="%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA_%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%AC"){
...code
}
```

in any cases doesn't work however it works fine with english characters.

Comment: var_dump($_GET) and see what you actually have to play with

Comment: Start by logging the contents of `$_GET['page']` to see what it contains in both cases. Also check that your script is saved with the right encoding (UTF-8)

Comment: Of course, we presume that the code above is not what you actually use, and that you use `==` and not `=` to compare!

Comment: @jcaron Probably a generous assumption

Comment: @jcaron Sorry All, it was a typo and happens twice because I copied and paste the code. It was an example and in real world I use equal operand ==

Comment: @edmondscommerce I echo $_GET['page'] then put it in compare string and no success

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't think so, With his assumption my code should work in any cases. even enter what i did not want.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly in PHP you cannot compare datatypes using a single `=` sign like this:  `if($_GET['page']="%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA_%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%AC"){echo 'ere';}`

Have a look [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.phphttp://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Your code will most probably work if you do this:

```
if($_GET['page']=="تست_پیج"){
    ...code
}
```

or

```
if($_GET['page']==="تست_پیج"){
    ...code
}
```

**EDIT**

The following code should work, I tested it in PHP.
[PHP Fiddle Example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/g2zs-akm0)

```
if($_GET['page']=="%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA_%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%AC"){
...code
}
```

Comment: Well it's a typo mistake on writing sample on this page, I use equal == operand. And your answer is not quite well because in this case I will get true result not false;

Comment: Why do you not just change the page query string to use parameters in English? Or you could have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: I have no problem When I send forms via html with GET and works fine. But When I enter value in url manually doesn't work. However with urlencode could resolve the problem but when I want to check in if statement, I have to use $_GET['page']=="%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA_%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%AC"